circuitikz: how to reduce distance between vee symbol and its label?
I like reduce distance between vee symbol and its label. For example:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz\draw (0,0) to[short,o-] ++ (1,0) 
                 node[vee] {$V_{\mathrm{EE}}$};
\end{document}



It seems that the arrow tip is really an arrow tip. So, maybe shorten >=-5pt or similar could work?

No, this can't work. I just checked the code, this seems not to be possible like this, because the code does not allow to pass a style to the path of the arrow. And where the arrow tip sits, is defined by the path. =(

The distance is, unfortunately, fixed (I never changed it for legacy compatibility, although in this case, I could have been a bit more daring, maybe).
So, probably, the easy way to do it is the one suggested by @jlab.
Anyway, since v1.5.0, you can add hooks, and you can change the arrows with real arrows (see the manual, 4.1.2.1 and 9.3.1), so if you really want, you can do what @Jasper Habicht suggested...
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{monopoles/vee/arrow={Straight Barb[angle=80:6pt, line width=0.8pt]}}
\makeatletter
    \def\ctikz@hook@start@draw@component@vee{\tikzset{shorten >=-5pt}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%%% notice also the dot here in o-. to fix the non-join of the wire
\tikz\draw (0,0) to[short,o-.] ++ (1,0)
                 node[vee] {$V_{\mathrm{EE}}$};
\end{document}



Yeah, I was looking for something like this +1. I need to test this first before to decide which solution is more simple for my intended use.

If you do not need it in a lot of places, I admit that I myself often use the @jlab solution --- that way, you can put the label beside the arrow, which sometimes saves you a lot of space. This is just a bit of a gimmick showing that it can be done, but I am the first one to admit that's not ideal.

I working on preparation of the second edition of one of mine text books, which has about 40 figures drawn by use of circuitikz , so your solution is very handy.

You can get the text anchor with (vee.text), if vee is the name of the node.
Use an empty named vee node
node[vee] (vee) {}

and another node for the text, at the anchor (vee.text), whose position can be customized
(vee.text) node[yshift=-3pt]  {$V_{\mathrm{EE}}$} ;

Example:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz
\draw (0,0) to[short,o-] ++ (1,0)
node[vee] (vee) {}
(vee.text) node[yshift=-3pt]  {$V_{\mathrm{EE}}$} ;

\end{document}



Ah, two successive nodes ... I was hope, that  exist some settings for wee node`˛ which define distance between symbol and label (text) which seems to be hardwired. So far +1, for acceptance I will wait for while if some other suggestion will appear
